# How to get percentile instead of rank

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SELECT where one of the lines I am using for percentile is:

```
NTILE(100) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY SUM(quantity)) as Percentile
```

The data looks like:

```
ItemID  |  Quantity  |  Price  |  TotalQ
ABC        10           14.50     38
ABC        4            14.25     38
DEF        32           22.41     34
ABC        24           14.10     38
GHI        8            8.50      20
GHI        12           8.60      20
DEF        2            22.30     34
```

However, the Percentile field ends up being just a ranking of every quantity for each ItemID.  I would like each row to measure the cumulative percent of volume for each transaction price (each row is an individual transaction) starting from the top and going down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing percentiles, I prefer doing the calculation myself -- it is easy enough with the window functions.  If you are using SQL Server 2012, you have the cumulative sum, and can do what you want as:

```
select itemId, quantity, price, TotalQ, cast(cumQ as float) / TotQ as Percentile
from (select t.*,
             sum(TotalQ) over (partition by ItemId) as TotQ,
             sum(TotalQ) over (partition by itemId order by TotalQ desc) as cumQ
      from t
     ) t
```

You can multiply the Percentile by 100 and truncate or round, if you want.

If you don't have SQL Server 2012, you can do the same thing with a correlated subquery:

```
select itemId, quantity, price, TotalQ, cast(cumQ as float) / TotQ as Percentile
from (select t.*,
             sum(TotalQ) over (partition by ItemId) as TotQ,
             (select sum(TotalQ) 
              from t t2
              where t2.itemId = t.ItemId and t2.TotalQ >= t.TotalQ
             ) as cumQ
      from t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

Won't this work?

```
SELECT
   *,
   1E0 * Quantity / TotalQ
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        SUM(Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemID) AS TotalQ
    FROM
        MyTable
    ) x
```

Or add required output please

Comment: This is still giving me the percentages of the total, instead of the cumulative percentile.